# SharePoint: Unable to fetch information from an external list

Tags: sharepoint, caml, bdc

I am trying to fetch information from an external list using the following CAML query.

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='EventID' />
    <Value Type='Guid'>98f68099-2ec8-4b68-95dc-607f0d50520b</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

The EventID field's type is Guid both in the database and the model. The `List.GetItems` methods throws the exception with the message "FieldRef". Just this message. The line

```
Debug.WriteLine("Static Name: " + field.StaticName + " - Internal Name: " +     field.InternalName + " - Type Display Name:" + field.TypeDisplayName);
```

gives the following information just before the `List.GetItems` call

```
Static Name: EventID - Internal Name: EventID - Type Display Name:Guid
```

Any idea how to resolved this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the above CAML query in a `<Query>` Element. Also, you may want to include the `<Method Name=Resolve List />` element.

One thing you'll need is to list all the fields you'll want visible in the `ViewFields` element.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464384.aspx) a link that'll hopefully help